# onupdate based on another field with sqlalchemy declarative base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I use sqlalchemy with the pyramid framework, and i want to link a person to his geographical department using his postcode.
So i try to use the onupdate argument when defining the department_id column define the department_id.
see fallowing code:

```
from datetime import date
from emailing.models import Base, DBSession
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode, Text, DateTime, Sequence, Boolean, Date, UnicodeText, UniqueConstraint, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, column_property, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    firstName = Column(Unicode(255))
    lastName = Column(Unicode(255))

    created_at = Column(Date, default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(Date, onupdate=func.now())

    department_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('department.id'), onupdate=dep_id_from_postcode)
    department = relationship("Department", backref='persons')


    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('firstName', 'lastName'), {})


    def dep_id_from_postcode(self):
        return int(self.postcode[:2])
```

on update for the updated_at field works fine, but for the deparment_id field it tell my:

> NameError: name 'dep_id_from_postcode' is not defined

i've found documentation about python executed function here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html?highlight=trigger#python-executed-functions
but nothing that uses another field to use in onupdate argument.

i hope i'm clear enought as i'm not a "natural english speaker"
Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has special mechanism for using other column value in default (i.e. onupdate) function called: Context-Sensitive Default Functions
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#context-sensitive-default-functions:

> The typical use case for this context with regards to default
>   generation is to have access to the other values being inserted or
>   updated on the row.

As Van pointed out you need to make sure that postcode is a field defined for Person or you'll need to add functionality that will take care about getting postcode associated with Person instance.

What worked for me - regular function, not bound to any object.
SQLAlchemy will call it at the time of insert and/or update and pass special argument with "context" - which is not actual object you are updating.

So for your example I would do something like this.

```
def dep_id_from_postcode(context):
    postcode = context.current_parameters['postcode']
    return int(postcode[:2])

class Person(Base):
    postcode = Column(String)
    # ...

    # ...
    department_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('department.id'), onupdate=dep_id_from_postcode)
    # ...
```

Be careful with this context argument - I end up with problem when context had None field's value in some cases if I not updating 'postcode' value with the same operation.

Eclipse with pydev with debugger helped me to see what information is passed as context.

Comment: thank you too, its just what i'm doing after readeing van's answer. the thing is context.current_parameters seems to be randomly filled (sometimes it contain a key postcode, sometime not (and it doesn't seem linked wherever i do or don't update the postcode field) (maybe because il a something as 20 other fieds in that class)

Comment: FYI, a more up to date link: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions

Comment: This will not work when you call `.update` with some values to update and they do not contain `'postcode'`.

Comment: Neat approach @vvladymyrov. But how do you call dep_id_from_postcode() from outside the model class, or rather what would you pass into that method as the value of 'context' if you had to call it from a client of `Person` like, let's say, from a unittest?

Answer (score 6):

Move the function definition before its usage:

```
class Person(Base):
    # ...
    def dep_id_from_postcode(self):
        return int(self.postcode[:2])
    # ...
    department_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('department.id'), onupdate=dep_id_from_postcode)
    # ...
```

Is the `postcode` really a field directly in `Person`? Because if it is not, you might need to handle this completely differently. For example, if the `postcode` is derived from the `primary_address` relationship, you need to check add/remove of the `primary_address` relationships and the changes in the related `Address` object for proper hooking.

Comment: i check this answer because van own the bonty since this was the post who help me to solve the problem, see also, second and my third post to have a complete answer

Comment: This would be a nice Pythonic API solution and it feels like it should work, but it definitely doesn't. The callable passed to `onupdate` doesn't receive `self` (e.g. in your case an instance of Person), it receives a special SQLAlchemy context object (some subclass of `DefaultExecutionContext`, depending on the DB engine). You can access the properties being passed in the SQL UPDATE statement, but not the properties of the model

Answer (score 1):

> Be careful with this context argument - I end up with a problem when context had None field's value in some cases if I not updating 'postcode' value with the same operation.

As @vvladymyrov mentioned that he ended up with the problem that context will produce None if in case you are using field values which you are not updating. But still, you need to calculate another one.

For Example:

You have firstName and lastName that will be taken as input from a user. You also have fullName that you calculate based on firstName and lastName. The following is the code which you follow:

```
#The below code is the ERModel class in sqlalchemy
def calculateFullName(context):
    name = context.current_parameters['firstName'] + " " + context.current_parameters['lastName']
    return name

class User(Base):
    firstName= Column(String)
    lastName= Column(String)
    name= Column(String,default=calculateFullName,onupdate=calculateFullName)
    # ...
    # ...
# End of ER Model
```

Now let's consider a case where you want to update a user's lastName and internally the name also should get updated by using the calculateFullName function you can achieve it but there is a caveat if you try to do the following:

```
user = session.query(User).filter(User.id=<id>).one() # Here you will get the specific user based on id.
user.lastName = "XXX" #This is the new value you want to be updated for the existing user.
session.update(user)
session.commit()
```

As mentioned, the above will call calculateFullName and you will get the context but in that context.current_parameters, the firstName will be None. (As you are not updating firstName you will get that value as None, if you want you can print(context.**dict**) to check what you are getting).

So the solution that I found for these kinds of cases (Update a column which depends on 2 columns on which the only one column is getting updated) is using session query update() function as following:

```
query = session.query(User).filter(User.id=<id>)  # This will return query object
query.update({"lastName"="XXX", "firstName"=query.one().__dict__.get("firstName")},syncronize_session=False)
```

As you are updating lastName and you need firstName to calculate the name. So you need to send firstName to context. As you already queried and get the current record from database to memory you can use that and send to query.update() such that you will get that in the context object.

**Note:** The approach that I took may not be the efficient one. Please guide me if I did any mistake. I am happy to learn.

Comment: Personally I believe that using the `@validates` approach is better than your solution. Neither is perfect but yours seems hacky as the same needs to be done in every place the update of such model is called.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708219/how-to-handle-sqlalchemy-onupdate-when-current-context-is-empty

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Thank you so much for the suggestion. I will take a look at it.

BTW, why sqlalchemy is not sending previous context and current context? If they send, then the problem is solved I guess. What say?

Comment: I checked it. In my case, fullName is dependent on firstName and lastName. If anyone of that is updated, I have to use both firstName and lastName to calculate the fullName. 

But the mentioned link talks about only one dependency right. How can I use validates to check if firstName changed then use both firstName and lastName to update fullName and vice versa? 

Please help me in understanding.

Comment: With dependency on two fields, your UPDATE either gets both name, or gets only one of it (then you have to get the second one somehow which might be doable in the way you do in your answer) or gets none. And in the last scenario, you probably don't want to update "name" and that's where the `@validates` might come in :-)

Comment: I got you. So still you prefer my answer as if we have a dependency on 2 fields. If it is on 1 field then better to use @validates. 

Thanks for that. Please comment on this if you find any better solution later. I will also do the same. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Guys, Any update on this issue? Please comment here. Thanks