# how to handle sqlalchemy onupdate when current context is empty?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model of article which will have slug based on it's title, the model is like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text

Base = declarative_base()


class Article(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    content = Column(Text)
    slug = Column(String(100), nullable=False,
                  default=lambda c: c.current_params['title'],
                  onupdate=lambda c: c.current_params['title'])
```

`slug` is taking title's value. So, everytime article `slug` will match it's title. But, when I edit the content without changing it's title, this
exception is raised

```
(builtins.KeyError) 'title' [SQL: 'UPDATE article SET content=?, slug=?,
updated_at=? WHERE article = ?'] [parameters: [{'article_id': 1,
'content': 'blah blah blah'}]]
```

I guess that because `current_params` doesn't contain `title`. If, I change
the `lambda` there and using `if`, slug will be `None`. So how can I handle
this and keep the slug value match it's title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [validates() decorator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    @validates('title')
    def update_slug(self, key, title):
        self.slug = title
        return title
```

Or [events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import event

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

@event.listens_for(Article.title, 'set')
def update_slug(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    target.slug = value
```

Comment: Note however that `@validates` triggers on both INSERT and UPDATE thus some might not consider this a viable substitute for `onupdate` (which was causing the problem in the question). It's an elegant solution though In cases when one have identical `default`+`onupdate` :-)