# SQLAlchemy: avoid updating a field with `onupdate` based on which other fields are being updated

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a table called `Host`, which defines two columns that are somewhat related - `mac_address` and `manufacturer`. The `manufacturer` field is determined using a public mapping between mac addresses to their owners (Hardware manufacturing companies).

Although `manufacturer` could be just a method in the ORM class, I would like to be able to filter based on it's value.

The problem I have with implementing an `onupdate` function is that I require the ability to *keep the value of manufacturer unchanged if a `mac_address` field was not provided for the update*, where to my understanding the previous `mac_address` value will not be available through `get_current_parameters`.

Simply put, I'm looking for a way to skip updating a field from within it's `onupdate` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle sqlalchemy onupdate when current context is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708219/how-to-handle-sqlalchemy-onupdate-when-current-context-is-empty)

Comment: See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712600/5484072, this seem to address the issue. Though I admit the solution presented there is not perfect (mostly because the `@validates` applies even on both INSERTs and UPDATEs, and not only when updating the record).

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69625550/5320906)