# ORM sqlalchemy create schema set column equal to calculation

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy ORM, is there a way to set a column equal to a calculation from other two columns? This would be similar to what MySQL generated columns.e.g.:

````
class FactStockQuantity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(BIGINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    value1 = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), index=True)
    value2 = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), index=True)
    value3 = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), index=True, value= value1 + value2)```
````

Comment: Have a look at [`context sensitive default functions`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions).

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11134539/6560549

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess it partially depends on if you need it to be in the db or not.

It looks like [Hybrid Attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) allow you to have "calculated column" functionality at the ORM level, but it's not actually creating the column in the database.

Otherwise, you can create it with SQL and then use FetchedValue to keep SQLAlchemy from trying to write a value to it, as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448572/2196270).

HTH